# need to change number of rows of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array in indice.php, included into my page.php, is an array exported from the table "indice" of my db.

```
<?php
$indice = array(
  array('id' => '1','def' => 'Admin'),
  array('id' => '2','def' => 'Utente'),
  array('id' => '31','def' => 'Aldwich Vertigos'),
  array('id' => '32','def' => 'Celtic Newcastle'),
  array('id' => '91','def' => 'Serie A'),
  array('id' => '92','def' => 'Serie B'),
  array('id' => '93','def' => 'Premier League'),
  array('id' => '110','def' => 'Argentina'),
  array('id' => '431','def' => 'Brisbane Road'),
  array('id' => '432','def' => 'Kingstone Park'),
  array('id' => '120','def' => 'Belgio') ); ?>
```

And my array is in this way:

```
array(416) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["def"]=>
    string(5) "Admin"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["def"]=>
    string(6) "Utente"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "31"
    ["def"]=>
    string(16) "Aldwich Vertigos"
...etc...
```

then i print this:

```
<?php
include("functions.php");
include("auth.php");
include("db.php");
include("indice.php");
                      $indiceok = $indice['2']['def'];
              echo $indiceok;
?>
```

'''

Well... My $indiceok stamps 'Aldwych Vertigos', but how could i obtain that $indiceok using the ID (2) stamps "Utente"?

I appreciate too a string which change my array in an array like this, using ID to identify my array selections:

```
array(416) {
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["def"]=>
    string(5) "Admin"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["def"]=>
    string(6) "Utente"
  }
  **[31]**=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "31"
    ["def"]=>
    string(16) "Aldwich Vertigos"
```

Many thanks and sorry for my question, i'm sure it's probably very easy to resolve, but i don't know how i can

Comment: Mauro I see that you are new here. If you read/take the tour you will even your first badge. https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for array_column.
By default it isolates a column in a multidimensional array but if you use the third argument you can make an array associative.

```
$yourarray = array_column($yourarray, Null, "id");
```

This will only work if id is unique.
If it's not unique, meaning you have two 31, the last subarray will be kept and the first will be truncated.

See result of your array here: https://3v4l.org/CJcJL

---

Alternatively, of your array is static you can just assign the keys manually in the code:

```
$indice = array(
  "1" => array('id' => '1','def' => 'Admin'),
  "2" => array('id' => '2','def' => 'Utente'),
  "31" => array('id' => '31','def' => 'Aldwich Vertigos'),
  "32" => array('id' => '32','def' => 'Celtic Newcastle'),
  "91" => array('id' => '91','def' => 'Serie A'),
  "92" => array('id' => '92','def' => 'Serie B'),
  "93" => array('id' => '93','def' => 'Premier League'),
  "110" => array('id' => '110','def' => 'Argentina'),
  "431" => array('id' => '431','def' => 'Brisbane Road'),
  "432" => array('id' => '432','def' => 'Kingstone Park'),
  "120" => array('id' => '120','def' => 'Belgio') );
```